# Java Recursion Exercise Confusion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to get my head around recursion. I am able to do some exercises that i have been doing, but i don't understand how this output comes to print the star seven times when you pass it in 5 as i, can someone explain it to me.

```
public static void quiz(int i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        quiz(i / 2);
        quiz(i / 2);
    }
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: I recommend walking through the code with debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your method will be executed like this:

```
quiz(5):
  is 5 > 1? yes
    quiz(2):
      is 2 > 1? yes
        quiz(1):
          is 1 > 1? no
          print *
        quiz(1):
          is 1 > 1? no
          print *
      print * 
    quiz(2):
      is 2 > 1? yes
        quiz(1):
          is 1 > 1? no
          print *
        quiz(1):
          is 1 > 1? no
          print *
      print * 
  print *
```

Now count number of stars printed.